# Angular Js Upload .csv File in Umbraco Backoffice and parse it?

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, csv, umbraco7

Im trying to upload a csv file within the back office of Umbraco. Im new to Angular so not exactly sure where i'm going wrong, wondered if someone could steer me in the right direction.

Here is the HTML:

```
<input type="file" id="clinicUpload" name="file" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().uploadFile(this.files)" accept=".csv" />
```

My Angular js is:

```
$scope.uploadFile = function(files) {
    var fd = new FormData();
    //Take the first selected file
    fd.append("file", files[0]);

    $http.post("/umbraco/backoffice/Api/Clinic/BulkUpload", fd, {
        withCredentials: false,
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'text/csv' },
        transformRequest: angular.identity
    })
    .success()
    .error();

};
```

My c# code is :

```
        public HttpResponseMessage BulkUpload()
    {

        try
        {
            var files = HttpContext.Current.Request;

            // Verify that the user selected a file
            if (files != null && files.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                // get the file stream in a readable way
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(files.InputStream);


                while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                {
                    var line = reader.ReadLine();
                    var values = line.Split(',');
                }
            }
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }
    }
```

The problem i'm having is when 'reader' reads each line im getting extra text in the file, something like:

> ------WebKitFormBoundaryDQ1Xx8AhG5dByO35  Content-Disposition:form-data; name="file"; filename="file.csv" 
>   Content-Type:application/octet-stream

Is there a better way of parsing this file without all the extra info added in? Am i uploading this file through Angular Js correctly? Should i be parsing this file differently in C#? 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe not entirely what you're looking for, but I once had to do the same thing and ended up using a 3rd party directive call ng-file-upload. Available on github: https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload